# Run integration test between ClickHouse from gnomock and kafka from dockertest in GO

Tags: docker, go, networking, apache-kafka, clickhouse

I have a Go application that use clickhouse to do some analytics, I am using the clickHouse kafka engine to consume data from kafka topic.
I am trying to write an integration test between the kafka and clickHouse, so I want to produce data to kafka topic, and check the final result on the clickHouse destination table.
I am using [gnomock](https://github.com/orlangure/gnomock) library to run clikchouse docker image, and [dockertest](https://github.com/ory/dockertest) to run kafka image, but the problem is the both are running on different network, and as far as I know I can not use predefined network with gnomock library. So any ideas how to resolve this issue ? or what is the best practice to run this test ?

Comment: Why not use the same library for each? You want a real clickhouse container, right? So don't mock it. Containers aren't mocks, anyway. They are real servers. If you want mocks, then don't start actual server processes or any containers. Also, Clickhouse has its own tests for Kafka integration, so, what are you hoping to test?

Comment: I am not trying to mock the containers, I want to run the docker container for integration test, the gnomock lib is already used to run clickhouse container, but now I use the clickHouse kafka engine, so I want to run the test end to end, like producing some data and check if the data are there in the clickHouse. the thing is the gnomock doesnot support network configuration, and switching to dockertest for clickHouse could be the solution, but that would require a lot of refactoring on my end, and I was trying to avoid this

Comment: You could also use Testcontainers, but yes, you'll need networking. But as mentioned, I think you'll effectively be duplicating existing Clickhouse tests of the Kafka engine when you should instead be testing the logic of your own app using interfaces and assuming Kafka and Clickhouse themselves will work as expected (by creating mocks/fakes and inject success/failure functions)